# Value cannot be null, parameter name key

Tags: sql, acumatica, schedule

Anyone have a way to solve this sql error when trying to automate schedule a custom filtered processing screen in acumatica?

Value Cannot be null, parameter name key.

Below is the stack trace. My ID field does have IsKey = true in the DAC and is a Primary Key in the sql script

```
12/20/2022 11:09:19 AM Error:
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key

   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.TryGetOrCreateValue(String key, PXView& value)
   at PX.Data.PXViewCollection.get_Item(String key)
   at PX.SM.AUScheduleMaint.OnScreenIdChanged(PXCache sender, AUSchedule schedule)
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnRowInserted(Object item, Object pending, Boolean externalCall)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data, Boolean bypassinterceptor)
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Insert(Object data)
   at PX.Data.PXSelectBase`1.Insert(Table item)
   at PX.Data.PXFilteredProcessing`2._ScheduleAdd_(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.RunHandler(PXAdapter adapter)
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__28.MoveNext()
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Web..1\PX.Web.UI.dll.il:line 110930
   at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) in C:\Users\svc-builder\AppData\Local\Temp\~PX.Web..1\PX.Web.UI.dll.il:line 108573
```

My ID field does have IsKey = true in the DAC and is a Primary Key in the sql script
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjNt7.png)

```
Filter DAC:
public class NGZoomProcessingFilter : IBqlTable
{
    #region OperationID

    [PXInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Operation ID")]
    [OperationIDEntityType]
    public virtual int? OperationID { get; set; }

    public abstract class operationID : 
PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<operationID>
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region OverrideLastRunDate

    [PXDate()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Override Last Run")]
    public virtual DateTime? OverrideLastRunDate { get; set; }

    public abstract class overrideLastRunDate : 
PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<overrideLastRunDate>
    {
    }

    #endregion

Main DAC:
{
[Serializable]
[PXCacheName("Zoom Processing Routine")]
public class NGZoomProcessingRoutine : IBqlTable
{
    public class PK : 
PrimaryKeyOf<NGZoomProcessingRoutine>.By<operationID>
    {
        public static NGZoomProcessingRoutine Find(
            PXGraph graph, int? operationID)
            => FindBy(graph, operationID);
    }

    #region Selected

    [PXBool]
    [PXUnboundDefault(false)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }

    public abstract class selected : BqlBool.Field<selected>
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region OperationID

    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Operation ID")]
    [OperationIDEntityType]
    public virtual int? OperationID { get; set; }

    public abstract class operationID : 
PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<operationID>
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region LastRun

    [PXDBDate()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Run")]
    public virtual DateTime? LastRun { get; set; }

    public abstract class lastRun : 
PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<lastRun>
    {
    }

    #endregion

Graph:
{
//PrepareDataScreen
public class NGZoomProcessing : PXGraph<NGZoomProcessing>
{
    public PXCancel<NGZoomProcessingFilter> Cancel;

    public PXFilter<NGZoomProcessingFilter>                                      
Filter;
    public PXFilteredProcessing<NGZoomProcessingRoutine, 
NGZoomProcessingFilter> ProcessingRoutine;

    public PXSetup<NGZoomProcessingSettings> Settings;

    public SelectFrom<NGPgtAIntroWebinarParticipant>.View 
Participants;

    public SelectFrom<NGPgtAIntroWebinarInstance>.View Webinars;

    protected void _(Events.RowSelected<NGZoomProcessingFilter> 
e)
    {
        if (e.Row is null) return;
        DateTime? lastRunDate = null;
        if (e.Row.OverrideLastRunDate is not null)
        {
            lastRunDate = e.Row.OverrideLastRunDate;
        }

        ProcessingRoutine.SetProcessDelegate((list) => 
SyncWebinars(list, lastRunDate));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at this, and its because you have IsKey=true on your filter DAC, remove it and your problem will go away